# Resume currently playing video in Google Cast 'ExpandedControlsActivity' rather than restarting

Tags: android, video, chromecast, google-cast

From my android phone if i again play an already TV casted video, the 'ExpandedControlsActivity' appears on phone and the video starts from beginning on TV. 
I don't want the video to start from beginning i just want it to continue playing on TV and to make 'ExpandedControlsActivity' resume with updated status from TV. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, yes. It is possible to resume currently playing video as Google Cast framework has this design feature as discussed in [sender resumes cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/sender#sender-control-resume).

With this, you may want to try using the [`SessionManagerListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/SessionManagerListener) class.

As discussed in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#how_session_management_works),

> Sessions are managed by the class `SessionManager`, which your app can access via `CastContext.getSessionManager()`. Individual sessions are represented by subclasses of the class `Session`. For example, `CastSession` represents sessions with Cast devices. Your app can access the currently active Cast session as `SessionManager.getCurrentCastSession()`.

Also, you can monitor session events such as resumption with the use of `SessionManagerListener` class. Google Cast framework automatically attempts to resume from an abnormal/abrupt termination while a session was active.

Here's an example on how you can manage sessions:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private CastSession mCastSession;
    private SessionManager mSessionManager;
    private final SessionManagerListener mSessionManagerListener =
            new SessionManagerListenerImpl();
    private class SessionManagerListenerImpl implements SessionManagerListener {
        @Override
        public void onSessionStarted(Session session, String sessionId) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSessionResumed(Session session, boolean wasSuspended) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSessionEnded(Session session, int error) {
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        mSessionManager = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this).getSessionManager();
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mCastSession = mSessionManager.getCurrentCastSession();
        mSessionManager.addSessionManagerListener(mSessionManagerListener);
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSessionManager.removeSessionManagerListener(mSessionManagerListener);
        mCastSession = null;
    }
}
```